# WebDriver press button Google play

Tags: java, button, selenium, webdriver

The task is press button "More" in https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/FINANCE/collection/topselling_paid

This is screenshot
http://c2n.me/i9LC1O

My code is:

```
String url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/FINANCE/collection/topselling_paid";
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(url);
//Collects ONLY first 60 link. `enter code here`But I need more....
        ArrayList<WebElement> linksToApp = (ArrayList<WebElement>) driver
                .findElements((By.className("title")));
        ArrayList<String> urlToApp = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Please, help me.

Comment: For me that button is hidden. Thus clicking it isn't going to achieve anything. As I scroll down the page, "showing more" is done automatically, and thus I have no idea whatsoever what you are trying to achieve, since that isn't what the page appears to do.

Comment: You didn`t see button "More". Am i right?

Comment: Yeah. From my investigation it doesn't ever get shown, the page automatically gets "more" results as you scroll down using AJAX requests.

Comment: Try to see "More" button with help of another browse, please.

Comment: Follow this link
https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/FINANCE/collection/topselling_paid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like

```
driver.findElement(By.id("id-of-show_more-button")).click();
```

You can find the element id byt right clicking on the element, click on inspect element and then checking for the id attribute in the HTML

Comment: I tried to do it
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='show-more-button']")).click();
But nothing happened. Please, tell me, whai is a problem.

Comment: Try using id as it is always more stable: In your case, it would be driver.findElement(By.id("show-more-button")).click(); You are using HTML unit driver and hence there won't be any display on screen. You should only be concerned with the logs. And also on a sidenote, I have seen that HTMLUnitDriver is not very stable in itself.

Comment: I tried to do like you told. But it does not work.
Collects ONLY first 60 link. But I need more....

Comment: Urgent! Help me any ony one,please!My skype is flexin777.